# saving skeleton data in file

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect

I would like to store skeleton data captured by kinect camera for future use on my hard disk or any folder. please can you help me??? I will retrieve the skeleton data in the future and use it for comparison in the future. Here is my code....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Kinect;

namespace KinectUserHeight
{
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        KinectSensor _sensor;
        Byte[] pixelData;
        string image_name;
        string[] joint_intdex;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            _sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Where(x => x.Status == KinectStatus.Connected).FirstOrDefault();

            if (_sensor != null)
            {
                _sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += new EventHandler<SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs>(Sensor_SkeletonFrameReady);
                _sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
                if (!this._sensor.ColorStream.IsEnabled)
                {
                    this._sensor.ColorStream.Enable();
                }
                this._sensor.ColorFrameReady += sensor_ColorFrameReady;
            }
        }

        // new   1
        void sensor_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e){
            using (ColorImageFrame imageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {
            // Check if the incoming frame is not null
            if (imageFrame == null)
            {
            return;
            }
            else
            {
            // Get the pixel data in byte array
            this.pixelData = new byte[imageFrame.PixelDataLength];
            // Copy the pixel data
            imageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.pixelData);
            // Calculate the stride
            int stride = imageFrame.Width * imageFrame.BytesPerPixel;
            // assign the bitmap image source into image control
            this.VideoControl.Source = BitmapSource.Create(
            imageFrame.Width,
            imageFrame.Height,
            96,
            96,
            PixelFormats.Bgr32,
            null,
            pixelData,
            stride);
            }
            }

        }

        void Sensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    canvas.Children.Clear();

                    Skeleton[] skeletons = new Skeleton[frame.SkeletonArrayLength];

                    frame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletons);

                    var skeleton = skeletons.Where(s => s.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (skeleton != null)
                    {
                        // Calculate height.
                        double height = Math.Round(skeleton.Height(), 2);

                        // Draw skeleton joints.
                           foreach (JointType joint in Enum.GetValues(typeof(JointType)))
                           {
                               DrawJoint(skeleton.Joints[joint].ScaleTo(640, 480));
                               string x = skeleton.Joints[joint].Position.X.ToString();
                               x_pos.Content = x;
                               joint_intdex[(int)joint] = x;
                           }
                         //  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
                        // Display height.
                        tblHeight.Text = "Height: " + height.ToString() + "m";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public string arrayToString(System.Collections.ArrayList ar)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings st = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
            st.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            st.Indent = false;
            System.Xml.XmlWriter w = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb, st);
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer s = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ar.GetType());
            s.Serialize(w, ar);
            w.Close();
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private void DrawJoint(Joint joint)
        {
            Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse
            {
                Width = 10,
                Height = 10,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCoral)
            };

            Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, joint.Position.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, joint.Position.Y);

            canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _sensor.Start();
        }

        private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _sensor.Stop();
        }

        private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            lblValue.Content = (int)slider1.Value;
        }

        private void btn_angleAdjust_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
            if (this._sensor.ElevationAngle < this._sensor.MaxElevationAngle || this._sensor.ElevationAngle > this._sensor.MinElevationAngle)
            this._sensor.ElevationAngle = (int)slider1.Value;
        }   

        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            image_name = image_handler.Text;
            image_name += ".png";

            string filePath =  nvironment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
            filePath = filePath + @"G:\thesis_picture\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            }

            //string path =     System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), image_name);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, image_name);
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    BitmapSource imageSource = (BitmapSource)VideoControl.Source;
                    JpegBitmapEncoder jpegEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    jpegEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageSource));
                    jpegEncoder.Save(fs);
                    fs.Close();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to limit your example code to just the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

The Kinect Skeleton is a serializable object.  You can read about serialization here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx

If you want something that already does the work, the Kinect Toolbox has a hook that will do it for you:

http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/